# What is the better design pattern with regard of Activities and Fragments and multiple lists/deep-dive navigation?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I have a list that's loaded with collections, and from it I navigate to another list with items (collection's items), and from it that I can expand the details (item's details) into a view with images, text, etc.

I have the option to create 3 activities or to create 1 activity with different fragments (and to do the management of VISIBLE / GONE by myself).

What is the best design option for those?

thanks a lot for any answer!

Answer (score 0):

either use the [Navigation Architecture Component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/) for that -

or just inflate the fragments into a content-holder fragment.

there is no "best option", because it depends what the result should be -

for example, on a phone it might make sense to switch activities or inflate,

while on a tablet, it might make sense to display two lists at once.

Comment: Thank you Martin. I looked at Navigation Arch. Comp, but that's still in Alpha and I cannot take a dependency by it. The experience for me will be same on the phone and tablet. I don't plan, for now, to make it different. I think that activities will make the code a bit more isolated, according with single resp. princ (srp), but in the same time I am a bit concern if the performance and state management (back and forth navigation between the list) will be impacted by using activities instead of fragments.

Comment: @user3053247 would assume, that with with such basic questions, it will be 1.0.0 final long before you have something release-able ready. and actually, there is not much difference concerning the separation of duties, if a Fragment holds to code or when an Activity holds the code; according to the design guidelines, Fragment would be way to go - but nevertheless, on a small screen using Activity can support the user in understanding (depending the surrounding buttons/menus on the main Activity - which would otherwise need to be inflated as, too - in order to match the displayed fragment).